# Function that calculates NPV from a list of cash flows

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance

trying to write a function that will calculate present value of list of cash flows. I know that numpy can do this very easily but for an assignment I have to write my own function for this :/.

Here are the three cash flows in a list as well as discount rate.

```
cfList = [20, 50, 90]           
r = 0.05
```

Here's the function i've written so far. f = 0 because I want to start with the first cash flow (in this case 20). i = 1 because for the first flow its raised to the 1st power and the second flow (50) will be squared and so on.

```
def npv(cfList, r):
    f = 0
    i = 1

    pv = cfList[f] / ((1 + r) ** i)

    while i < len(cfList):
        f += 1
        i += 1
        return pv


print(npv(cfList, r))
```

However, this output only gives me the PV of the first cashflow, and not the sum of all three from the list. If you can help i appreciate it so much thanks !

Comment: So you want to sum up the NPV of the cash flows? What is your expected result for the example you've given. The `return` in the `while` loop means it will exit immediately which is unlikely what you want, you aren't calculating the subsequent terms which you probably want to add to `pv` and then `return pv` outside of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sum the individual cashflows within your function and return that. At the moment you are returning the value of pv of the first cashflow as you have a return statement in your for loop.

Also, I think the way you check your while loop against `i` will mean that you'll miss the last payment value. Usually you don't need to instantiate counter variables yourself (see my examples below):

```
def npv(cfList, r):
    f = 0
    i = 1

    pv = cfList[f] / ((1 + r) ** i)  # <-- this needs to be in the loop

    while i < len(cfList): # <-- i will break loop before last payment is calculated.
        f += 1
        i += 1
        return pv  # <-- this return here is the issue


print(npv(cfList, r))
```

NPV being the sum of PV of all future cashflows, that is what you need to calculate. E.g.:

```
def npv(cfList, r):

    sum_pv = 0  # <-- variable used to sum result

    for i, pmt in enumerate(cfList, start=1):  # <-- use of enumerate allows you to do away with the counter variables.
        sum_pv += pmt / ((1 + r) ** i)  # <-- add pv of one of the cash flows to the sum variable

    return sum_pv  # <-- only return the sum after your loop has completed.
```

Always remember that a `return` statement in a for-loop will break out of the loop the first time the `return` is encountered.

An alternate implementation would be to yield individual PVs from a PV generator and sum the results:

```
def pv_gen(cfList, r):

    for i, pmt in enumerate(cfList, start=1):

        yield pmt / ((1 + r) ** i)

print(sum(pv_gen(cfList, r)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning the NPV of a list of cash flows would look like:

```
def npv(cfList, r):
    return sum(f / ((1 + r) ** i) for i, f in enumerate(cfList, 1))

In []:
cfList = [20, 50, 90]
r = 0.05
npv(cfList, r)

Out[]:
142.14447683835436
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're iterating across the list using the while loop, then you should have the action taking line of code *within* the while loop.

It also looks like your loop will be cutting early as i = 2 = len(cflist) on the second iteration (don't forget that [python uses 0 based indexing](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html)) and because the return call is within the while loop.

This should work:

```
def npv(cfList, r):
    f = 0
    i = 1

    pv = 0

    while f <= len(cfList):
        pv += (cfList[f] / ((1 + r) ** i))
        f += 1
        i += 1
    return pv
```

Comment: thank you, and @SuperShoot, for yalls help and explanation, so much clearer now